# Terrestrial Space Elevator Construction - Plausability

Tags: orbital-motion, earth, rocket-science, rigid-body-dynamics

Framework

If there was a cable constructed at the equator about the circumference of the Earth, and if this cable had sufficient strength to remain intact while erect, call this tensile strength T.

Question

With a rocket, could you launch the cable from the surface of the Earth without exceeding the tensile strength T?

[image]

Comment: Generally, the strength required to stay erect is compressive, although this is reversed for a space elevator. But if that's not your intention, since it is constructed "about" the Earth's circumference. So it's not clear what direction your concept is facing in. I have no idea what the intention of attaching a rocket to a tether is either.

Comment: The cable is constructed around the Earth, this way the compression of the cable is only radially. The cable is brought into orbit by attaching a rocket to one end, and launching it into space. This will keep tension in the cable, so when the cable is being erected, the compressive strength of the material can be neglected. My question is whether the force on the cable as it is pulled into orbit will be greater than the force on the cable when it is in GEO. i.e, will the cable designed as a space elevator break if it is pulled into space.

Comment: The heart of my question is that there would be tremendous force as the rocket launched, but it would be at the strongest part of the cable. As the rocket moves far from the surface of the Earth, the tension from the rocket decreases but the  tension from the weight of the cable increases. Will the sum of the forces on the cable be largest when the cable is erect or will they peak at some point during the rocket's flight.

Comment: Ok, I can understand the idea now. The only comment I would make is that the elevator will start out wrapped around the equator a large number of times. I can't easily rule this out.

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277688/space-elevator-solved